# Help me tag my post?

Tags: support, tags

I'm not sure if I should be posting this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518083/my-files-can-i-save-forms-locally-against-secured-pages, on StackOverflow or Superuser?  I feel like I'm looking for some kind of browser hack that would require code; on the other hand, I'm just trying to find a customization for my browser, or if one exists that serves the intended purpose....

About the tags, I think that there may be some more specific terminology than 'saving', and I wonder if someone can help me find that term?

Comment: This is better fit for the chat.

Comment: What is? What chat man?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the question stands now, it's off-topic for Stack Overflow, since it is not programming related and you're asking for a browser plugin; as such I've voted to migrate your question to Super User.

If, on the other hand, you were to try writing your own plugin, it would be perfectly on-topic to ask at Stack Overflow, provided you have a go first, and then come back with a specific problem.

At the moment, I think you'll get more luck at Super User. If your question receives enough votes to migrate it, it will be moved there shortly.

Comment: Thanks.  It's very nice of you to help migrate the question.